# How to remove curly braces from the xml using C# code

Tags: c#

Need to know how to remove curly braces from the `xml` code for `C#`

```
{<RESPONSE>   <RESPONSE_TEXT>Registered P_UK4EZI</RESPONSE_TEXT>   <RESULT>OK</RESULT>   <RESULT_CODE>-1</RESULT_CODE>   <TERMINATION_STATUS>SUCCESS</TERMINATION_STATUS>   <MAC_KEY>KZzTDdNErHVNZzRRfKyrbuAj++J20IAF4XpmsmQFjdV7G4PauwHkUobkhEzjPRbD9GNUq5EtoOauxTSZHgsDeLx6FAWasSKb2FcsC7SMmCTV5VW4Wd5w+9tP1Hzy93wnedKPggExJbxA3BH8xvFjqvmiCHjB92fsPfHWXcqfMHhoRW8quA/B6jx44dm</MAC_KEY>   <MAC_LABEL>P_UK4EZI</MAC_LABEL>   <ENTRY_CODE>1570</ENTRY_CODE> </RESPONSE>}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just **[edit] the question** and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Also please see **[ask]**.

Comment: Do you always know that the first and last characters are braces? How much do you know about string manipulation, such as Substring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string original = "{<RESPONSE>   <RESPONSE_TEXT>Registered P_UK4EZI</RESPONSE_TEXT>   <RESULT>OK</RESULT>   <RESULT_CODE>-1</RESULT_CODE>   <TERMINATION_STATUS>SUCCESS</TERMINATION_STATUS>   <MAC_KEY>KZzTDdNErHVNZzRRfKyrbuAj++J20IAF4XpmsmQFjdV7G4PauwHkUobkhEzjPRbD9GNUq5EtoOauxTSZHgsDeLx6FAWasSKb2FcsC7SMmCTV5VW4Wd5w+9tP1Hzy93wnedKPggExJbxA3BH8xvFjqvmiCHjB92fsPfHWXcqfMHhoRW8quA/B6jx44dm</MAC_KEY>   <MAC_LABEL>P_UK4EZI</MAC_LABEL>   <ENTRY_CODE>1570</ENTRY_CODE> </RESPONSE>}";


original = original.Replace("{","").Replace("}","");
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vExrEE